# Altering a table primary key which has foreign key constrains in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table, mysql-error-1025

I have a mysql database which have set of tables One table have a composite key as the primary key and and a single foreign key. Following are the table definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ohrm_emp_education` (
  `emp_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `education_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `institute` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` decimal(4,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_number`,`education_id`),
  KEY `education_id` (`education_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



ALTER TABLE `ohrm_emp_education`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ohrm_emp_education_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_number`) REFERENCES `hs_hr_employee` (`emp_number`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `ohrm_emp_education_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`education_id`) REFERENCES `ohrm_education` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But now I need to add a new column to this existing table and make it as the primary key. I tried it with the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE ohrm_emp_education
ADD column id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD primary key (id)
```

But it shows following error

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './test/#sql-4f6_19b' to './test/ohrm_emp_education' (errno: 150)
```

I tried with several answers which are found on the internet but couldn't solve it properly.  Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete foreign keys first, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `ohrm_emp_education` DROP FOREIGN KEY `emp_number`;
ALTER TABLE `ohrm_emp_education` DROP FOREIGN KEY `education_id`;
```

And then alter table.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio.
Then right click on the table and click design. 
Then right click on the row which contains the composite key
and click on remove primary key
then add new column
and insert data into that column
and check that the column has no empty data.

Then again go to design view
and right click on the required column and click on Set as Primary Key

You're Done!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm searching for a way we can do it using pure sql commands, not in ui. I manged to get the answer by dropping the foreign keys first.

Answer (score 1):

You usually get this error if your tables use the InnoDB engine. In that case you would have to drop the foreign key, and then do the alter table and drop the column.

Answer (score 1):

drop/disable foreign key constraint. Drop primary key, add new PK, enable/add fk.